# Object creation issue in Django unittest

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a Django testcase, and I'm creating some objects in setUp:

```py
OBJ_COUNT = 4

class ObjTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        for i in range(OBJ_COUNT):
            Obj.objects.create()
```

Running this test results in 5, not 4 objects.

Comment: The `5` is not printed by the `range(..)` that is likely printed somewhere else. There is likely a `print(..)` statement in your model, view, ... that does this.

Comment: Unless of course you have somewhere imported something with the name `range` that thus overrides the reference to the "original" `range(..)`.

Comment: Note that your output is missing ``4`` - the ``5`` is not a result of the ``print`` in your code.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If OBJ_COUNT is 3, it outputs 0 1 2 4.

Comment: @rkardashov ``range`` is a builtin with well-defined semantics. In the code shown, it will behave exactly as described.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sure, it's builtin, and it worked OK until I upgraded the django from 2.1.7 to 2.2.3, to have the ability to use intermediate models in many-to-many relationship fields.

Answer (score 0):

The test database was the issue.

I'm keeping the db to make tests run faster:

```
$ ./manage.py test appname --keepdb
```

At some point, after a migration or whatever, the database become broken: it always had 1 Obj object at the start of each test run.

After a test run on a clean DB (without `--keepdb`), it started to work as expected.